# Condition on two fields

Tags: sql-server

I have a SQL Select and I am not sure how I can achieve this.  I am checking two fields to see if any of those fields are in a list.  So like,

```
Select * from MyTable where col1 or col2 in (select col3 from OtherTable where ID=1)
```

I tried

```
Select * from MyTable where 
col1  in (select col3 from OtherTable where ID=1)
or col2 in (select col3 from OtherTable where ID=1)
```

But, this returns the records that match first condition (only returns col1, but not col2) for some reasons.

Comment: col2 and col3 have the same data type?

Comment: and you have rows that can match the second (col2) condition ?

Comment: Yes, both col2 and col3 are the same data type. And, I have rows that can match the second condition. I did play with parentheses and looks like that did the trick.  Thanks everyone for help.

Comment: Can you explain and tell which one worked for you?

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
Select * from MyTable where 
(col1  in (select col3 from OtherTable where ID=1))
or 
(col2 in (select col3 from OtherTable where ID=1) )
```

Answer (score 0):

if you're subquery is the same for both columns, i'd throw it into a cte, then do a left outer join on the cte on col1 and col2, then do your where statement.

```
;with c3 as
(
    select col3
    from OtherTable
    where ID=1
)

select m.*
from MyTable m
    left outer join c3 as c1
        on m.col1=c1.col3
    left outer join c3 as c2
        on m.col2=c2.col3
where 
    (c1.col3>'')
    or (c2.col3>'')
```

if a blank varchar that isn't null is a viable option, change your where clauses to >=.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t.*
FROM MyTable t
  INNER JOIN (
    select col3
    from OtherTable
    where ID=1
  ) sel ON sel.col3 IN (t.col1, t.col2)
```